# Replace image in mobile apps

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using Phonegap/cordova.

I have

```
<img id="clothes" src="pictures/white.jpg" width="100%" >
```

and I have div colors

```
<a href="#FE4C04" style="text-decoration:none;">
  <div style="width:16%;height:20%;background-color:#FE4C04;margin:2%;float:left;">&nbsp</div>
</a>
<a href="#1498C8" style="text-decoration:none;">
  <div style="width:16%;height:20%;background-color:#1498C8;margin:2%;float:left;">&nbsp</div>
</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("[href='#FE4C04']").click(function(){    
    $('#clothes').attr('src','aa.jpg');
  });

  $("[href='#1498C8']").click(function(){ 
    $('#clothes').attr('src','ab.jpg');
  });
```

I want to click div color and then change image. This code works on desktop browser but if I try on device (e.g. Android), the image doesn't change.

I have tried many ways, but wasn't able to resolve this issue.

Comment: `'src','pictures/ab.jpg'` maybe?

Comment: ok,but this doesn't change too.

Comment: Is "#FE4C04" a page? If yes, the image is inside that page? If yes, `$("#FE4C04 #clothes").attr(...)`. And replace `.ready` with `pagecreate`. Use JQM events to attach listeners.

Comment: the image not inside the page. i want to replace img in a page mobile

Comment: Read my comment in my answer. You probably have a click issue inside the Webview on Android. This is a know issue, depending on  what Android version you are using together with what JQM version you are using. You can use (vclick) instead which simulates a mouse click, hence why it works on the desktop and not for Android.